# What are the proper chown and chmod syntax?

Tags: chmod, chown

I am trying to change ownership of a file/directory and seem to be doing something wrong, is it my syntax or...what?

```
michael@michael-desktop:/media/michael/Films$ ls -l
total 1536
drwxr-xr-x 2 michael michael 524288 Jan 17 19:04 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxr-xr-x 5 michael michael 524288 Jan 17 12:36  MEDIA
drwxr-xr-x 3 michael michael 524288 Jan 17 12:21 'System Volume Information'
michael@michael-desktop:/media/michael/Films$ sudo chown michael:root MEDIA
[sudo] password for michael: 
chown: changing ownership of 'MEDIA': Operation not permitted
michael@michael-desktop:/media/michael/Films$ chmod 777 MEDIA
michael@michael-desktop:/media/michael/Films$ ls -l
total 1536
drwxr-xr-x 2 michael michael 524288 Jan 17 19:04 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
drwxr-xr-x 5 michael michael 524288 Jan 17 12:36  MEDIA
drwxr-xr-x 3 michael michael 524288 Jan 17 12:21 'System Volume Information'
michael@michael-desktop:/media/michael/Films$ chown root:root MEDIA
chown: changing ownership of 'MEDIA': Operation not permitted
michael@michael-desktop:/media/michael/Films$
```

Sorry I couldn't figure out a screenshot but I'll tackle that at another time if that's OK.

Comment: You cannot change ownership to root as normal user. You have to switch to root

Comment: well that post didn't seem to workout the way i intended. I posted the contents of my terminal in lieu of a screen shot now i doni know what to do...

Comment: Try to switch to root "sudo su" and then try it again

Comment: michael@michael-desktop:/media/michael/Films$ sudo chown root:root MEDIA
[sudo] password for michael: 
chown: changing ownership of 'MEDIA': Operation not permitted
michael@michael-desktop:/media/michael/Films$ 

Here is what i got after using the root user.

Comment: Are you sure "michael" is the root ? Find out by looking into "/etc/passwd" find "michael" there and look if he has user ID equal to 0

Comment: Windows does not support Linux permissions.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change those attributes on a FAT file system.